# jQuery chain ajax calls

Tags: jquery, promise

I cannot for the life of me understand why this is not working ...

```
function Register(email, password) {

var data = {
    Email: email,
    Password: password,
    ConfirmPassword: password
};

return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: baseUrl + 'api/Account/Register',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
})

}

function Login(email, password) {

var data = {
    grant_type: 'password',
    username: email,
    password: password
};

return $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: baseUrl + 'Token',
    data: data
}).done(function (data) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(tokenKey, data.access_token);
});

}
```

Now ... I want to Register and then Login in one button click ...

```
var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
var password = $('input[name="password"]').val();

Register(email, password).then(Login(email, password))
```

But, that code does NOT call them in order. It does Login first usually.

I have also tried done() and when(), but I honestly do not understand the difference and would love some help ... *cries*

Comment: I believe you need to add async: false to your ajax calls. But I wouldn't do it this way. It'll hold off until ajax is done running. I would put the login in the success function of your ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that it is evaluating `Login(email, password)` immediately.

Try:
`Register(email, password).then(function() { Login(email, password); });`

Comment: Thank you, this worked ... I hate javascript ... Any insight on why you need the additional wrapper function?

Comment: The way you were calling it, it would first call `Register` and then call `Login` because it was passing the value returned from the `Login` function to `.then()`. By adding the wrapper, the `Login` function isn't executed until the deferred returned by `Register` has been resolved.

Comment: @hatcyl - Javascript is no different than most languages in this regard.  If you pass `Login(xxx)` as an argument to a function or method, it will be called immediately in all languages I know.  This is not just a Javascript thing.  Passing a function reference (so it can be called later) is a different syntax than calling a function now and passing its return result.  What you did is just a common programming mistake, not something that is unique to Javascript.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Yes you are right, not necessarily a javascript thing, I am just not used to this pattern. Truthfully, any new pattern takes getting used to.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Register(email, password) {

    var data = {
        Email: email,
        Password: password,
        ConfirmPassword: password
    };

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: baseUrl + 'api/Account/Register',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(msg) {
            Login(email, password);
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: thank you, although that will work, it gets ugly quickly when you need to chain many functions together, and sometimes conditionally. I am trying to use it the "promises" way ... but I'm a big noob.